# WEB-INF - Jar of Jars

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere, manifest

Mine is a web application. I have created a Jar containing some custom code and a few 3rd party jars. I have copied the custom jar to WEB-INF/lib folder. To make the 3rd party jars inside my jar visible to the application during deployment/runtime, what needs to be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Read up a bit on Web application Archive (WAR) files and how they work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [Jar Jar Links](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).  I don't believe there's a way to reference Jars inside another Jar.

Answer (score -2):

Im pretty sure it should work without any additional modifications.  The JVM should register the inner jars within the classpath and do its thing as normal.